# Does there exists a complete Kaehler metric with positive scalar curvature on certain strongly pseudoconvex manifolds?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

The more detailed question is as follows. Let $X$ be a projective manifold and $(L,h)$ a holomorphic line bundle on $X$ with a smooth hermitian metric whose curvature $\sqrt{-1}\, \Theta_h$ is a strictly positive $(1,1)$-form. Suppose that $s$ is a holomorphic section of $L$ with $\mathrm{div}(s)$ a smooth hypersurface. We set
$X_c := \big\{x\in X \,\big|\,  |s|_h > c\big\}$ for any $c>0$. Does $X_c$ admit a complete Kaehler metric with quasi-positive scalar curvature? ("quasi-positive" means nonnegative everywhere and strictly positive somewhere.)